# I am lost on recursion for php. How do I set it up, stop it, and know when to use it?

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could help me better understand recursion and how it is applicable in PHP.

Maybe a real life example or two for how it could benefit me ?

Are there different types of recursion?

Also how does the computer know to stop the recursion? Are there better uses than others for recursion?

When should I use it over other methods?

Comment: Any tutorial teaching recursion comes with an example, typically it's the faculty function. Check out it's mathematical definition, then try to program it, without and with recursion.

Comment: This is not really a PHP question, or a specific programming question it's a "what is recursion and how do I use it?" question.  Read the wiki article, google search for some tutorials and read or watch them, then try to code some specific examples yourself.  If you get stuck, then try to debug them by writing what's happening on paper or using debugging tools like adding echo statements.

Comment: Also, please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think you mean *factorial* function.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, you're completely right, that was an error translating German to English.

Comment: Generally if you have something like a data structure that has an arbitrary depth, eg: a tree, and you want to traverse it you can either write nested loops until your fingers fall off, or you can write a recursive function. The simplest concrete example being a filesystem as kainaw's answer illustrates.

Comment: Also, you should disabuse yourself of the notion that a computer "knows" how to do anything. Computers are dumb machines that do what programmers tell them, it is up to the programmer to know how and/or when to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is not special. It simply means that a function calls itself. So, write a function. Have that function call itself. For a PHP example, assume that I have a function that does something to a directory. I want to recursively do something to the directory. So:

```
function myrecdirfunc($dir)
{
  $dh = opendir($dir);
  while($file = readdir($dh))
  {
    if($file{0} == '.') continue; // Avoid . and ..
    if(is_dir($file)) myrecdirfunc($file);
    else dosomething($file);
  }
}
```

It doesn't matter what this function does. It only matters that about halfway through it, the function calls itself. So, it is recursion. If you want a much simpler example, you can have a pointless:

```
function countdown($n)
{
  if($n<=0) print "Blastoff";
  else countdown($n-1);
}
```

That is a function that calls itself. It is recursion. It is a bad use of recursion (tail-end recursion is always bad). But, it is still recursion.

Comment: Can you please explain how "tail-end recursion is always bad"? As far as I'm aware, some languages optimize tail-end recursion, so it's the opposite of bad.

Comment: @mpen First, this is a question about PHP, not "some languages." Second, some languages turn tail-end recursion into a loop when compiling - which optimizes it. If you had written it as a loop to start with, it wouldn't need to be optimized. Third, some languages are not optimal and never will be because they are based on heavy recursion. So, we are discussing turning something that is very very sluggish into something that is just very sluggish. To get into a complete answer, we need to discuss how the implementation of the recursive function works at an OS level.

Comment: @kainaw How is tail end different from another type of recursion and what makes it so bad?

Comment: @kainaw Okay, but what makes it worse than regular recursion then [in PHP]?

Comment: Tail end recursion is trivially easy to write as a loop. As a function, you take what is a loop and add extra function calls and variable copying. That uses time and resources where it is not needed.